# What can't microdnf do compared to dnf?

Tags: rhel, dnf

Microdnf's [README](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/microdnf#readme) says that it is "A minimal dnf for (mostly) Docker containers that uses libdnf and hence doesn't require Python."

It doesn't list `microdnf`'s features and doesn't expand on what sense it is "minimal" compared to `dnf`.

Red Hat's [Atomic Base Image annoucement](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/introducing-red-hat-enterprise-linux-atomic-base-image) mentions that "Microdnf is not a full yum replacement" but it also doesn't expand on what's missing.

There is a [man page](https://www.mankier.com/8/microdnf) online -- I'm not sure how official it is -- but it also doesn't expand on what's the gap compared to `dnf`.

The question is: what is the gap between `microdnf` and `dnf`? What can only be done with `dnf` and not with `microdnf`? Is there a resource that lists that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It doesn't list microdnf's features and doesn't expand on what sense it is "minimal" compared to dnf.

As minimal as stated: no Python and no Python module dependencies. Which are quite many packages to think of it.

```
rpm -q --requires dnf
python3-dnf = 4.2.23-4.el8
```

```
rpm -q --requires python3-dnf
python3-gpg
python3-hawkey >= 0.48.0-3
python3-libcomps >= 0.1.8
python3-libdnf
python3-libdnf >= 0.48.0-3
python3-rpm >= 4.14.2-35
```

The actual dependency tree will expand far more if each python module dependency is checked.

> what is the gap between microdnf and dnf

I *suppose* the actual gap will come also from the fact of not using Python:

- There is no Python interface, and thus you can't invoke `microdnf` from a Python code using a consistent API. You'll have to resort to using the `subprocess` Python module
- Actual `dnf` can be expanded with many additional commands provided by the `dnf-plugins-core` and other plugin packages. You may not expect [any of those features](https://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in `microdnf`. They will hardly ever make it to `microdnf`.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered microdnf can't install package groups. I have to install full yum or dnf if I want to do that.